# how to fix "xinit: unable to connect to X server" in nodejs exec

Tags: node.js, linux, xserver

My Xserver does not start from the nodejs script. I have to run it as root because otherwise the following error occurs:

> /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server

so I start the script as

> sudo node controller.js

First I start my controller to run a locale webserver. Then I want to start my Xorg server and run my chromium-browser per xinit command.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const config = require('./config.json');
const shell = require('shelljs');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var filePath = '.' + request.url;
    if(filePath == './'){
        filePath = config.baseFile;
    }
    var extname = path.extname(filePath);
    var contentType='text/html';
    switch(extname){
        case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript';
            break;
        case '.css':
            contentType = 'text/css';
            break;
        case '.json':
            contentType = 'application/json';
            break;
        case '.png':
            contentType = 'image/png';
            break;      
        case '.jpg':
            contentType = 'image/jpg';
            break;
        case '.wav':
            contentType = 'audio/wav';
            break;
    }
    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
        if (error) {
            if(error.code == 'ENOENT'){
                fs.readFile('./404.html', function(error, content) {
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                    response.end(content, 'utf-8');
                });
            }
            else {
                response.writeHead(500);
                response.end('Sorry, check with the site admin for error: '+error.code+' ..\n');
                response.end(); 
            }
        }
        else {
            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
            response.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
shell.exec('xinit chromium-browser --start-maximized -kiosk http://localhost:8080/');
```

> (EE)
>  Fatal server error: 
>  (EE) Server is already active for
>   display 0
>  If this server is no longer running, remove
>   /tmp/.X0-lock and start again.
>  (EE)
>  (EE)
>  Please consult
>   the The X.Org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help.
>   (EE)
>  No protocol specified
>  xinit: giving up
>  xinit: unable
>   to connect to X server: Resource temporarily unavailable
>  xinit:
>   server error

I deleted this file multiple times. I use the raspberry stretch lite distro.

> $ ps auxw | grep X
>   pi 949 0.0 0.0 3536 624 tty1 S+ 16:38 0:00 xinit /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc :0 vt1 -keeptty -auth /tmp/serverauth.wsn7HgMgWE 
>   root 949 0.0 3.9 182112 37440 tty1 S1 16:38 0:00 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp :0 vt1 -keeptty -auth /tmp/serverauth.wsn7HgMgWE 
>   pi 1188 0.0 0.0 4772 572 tty5 R+ 17:18 0:00 grep --color=auto X